# Draw small circle images over triangle in ios

Tags: ios, image, drawing, geometry

I have a Triangle ,On which I am going to put hollow circles to create a Garland(we can call it rosary).
Each circle is an image which I need to put on triangle on specific place.

Guys, Let me know How would I make it possible?If you need more clarity on this, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u mention some code say for the triangle

Answer (score 0):

like this:

Objective-C:

```
UIBezierPath* polygonPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[polygonPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(80.5, 33)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(119.9, 101.25)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(41.1, 101.25)];
[polygonPath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[polygonPath fill];

UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(58, 56, 45, 45)];
[UIColor.redColor setFill];
[ovalPath fill];
```

Swift:

```
var polygonPath = UIBezierPath()
polygonPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(80.5, 33))
polygonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(119.9, 101.25))
polygonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(41.1, 101.25))
polygonPath.closePath()
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
polygonPath.fill()

var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(58, 56, 45, 45))
UIColor.redColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
```

Both produce this:

[image]

or this:

Objective-C:

```
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(40, 18, 91, 91)];
[UIColor.redColor setFill];
[ovalPath fill];

UIBezierPath* polygonPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[polygonPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(85.5, 18)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(124.9, 86.25)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(46.1, 86.25)];
[polygonPath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[polygonPath fill];
```

Swift:

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(40, 18, 91, 91))
UIColor.redColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()

var polygonPath = UIBezierPath()
polygonPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(85.5, 18))
polygonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(124.9, 86.25))
polygonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(46.1, 86.25))
polygonPath.closePath()
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
polygonPath.fill()
```

For this:

[image]

And with a frame:

Objective-C:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(75, 28, 76, 66);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
CGContextClipToRect(context, frame);

UIBezierPath* polygonPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[polygonPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 1.48684 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.42424 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 1.98823 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 1.42424 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.98546 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 1.42424 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[polygonPath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[polygonPath fill];

UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + floor((CGRectGetWidth(frame) - 44) * 0.50000 + 0.5), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + floor((CGRectGetHeight(frame) - 44) * 1.00000 + 0.5), 44, 44)];
[UIColor.redColor setFill];
[ovalPath fill];

CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Swift:

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

```
let frame = CGRectMake(75, 28, 76, 66)

CGContextSaveGState(context)
CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, nil)

CGContextClipToRect(context, frame)

var polygonPath = UIBezierPath()
polygonPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.minX + 1.48684 * frame.width, frame.minY + 0.42424 * frame.height))
polygonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.minX + 1.98823 * frame.width, frame.minY + 1.42424 * frame.height))
polygonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(frame.minX + 0.98546 * frame.width, frame.minY + 1.42424 * frame.height))
polygonPath.closePath()
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
polygonPath.fill()

var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(frame.minX + floor((frame.width - 44) * 0.50000 + 0.5), frame.minY + floor((frame.height - 44) * 1.00000 + 0.5), 44, 44))
UIColor.redColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()


CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context)
CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

This obviously isn't going to draw a bunch of small circles in the triangle, but you've not specified how many circles need to be drawn and so it's impossible to help you further without this very important information, but this will give you a start.

And for reference, here's where you'll need to visit, the following information is dealing with packing problems and math, specifically packing problems with fitting circls inside of triangles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles

http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/crt/crt.html#Download

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_an_equilateral_triangle

and then this:

> Dense Packings of Equal Disks in an Equilateral Triangle R. L. Graham,
>   B. D. Lubachevsky
>
> Previously published packings of equal disks in an equilateral
>   triangle have dealt with up to 21 disks. We use a new discrete-event
>   simulation algorithm to produce packings for up to 34 disks. For each
>   n in the range 22≤n≤34 we present what we believe to be the densest
>   possible packing of n equal disks in an equilateral triangle. For
>   these n we also list the second, often the third and sometimes the
>   fourth best packings among those that we found. In each case, the
>   structure of the packing implies that the minimum distance d(n)
>   between disk centers is the root of polynomial Pn with integer
>   coefficients. In most cases we do not explicitly compute Pn but in all
>   cases we do compute and report d(n) to 15 significant decimal digits.
>
> Disk packings in equilateral triangles differ from those in squares or
>   circles in that for triangles there are an infinite number of values
>   of n for which the exact value of d(n) is known, namely, when n is of
>   the form Δ(k):=k(k+1)2. It has also been conjectured that d(n−1)=d(n)
>   in this case. Based on our computations, we present conjectured
>   optimal packings for seven other infinite classes of n, namely
>
> ```
> n=Δ(2k)+1,Δ(2k+1)+1,Δ(k+2)−2,Δ(2k+3)−3,Δ(3k+1)+2,4Δ(k), and 2Δ(k+1)+2Δ(k)−1.
> ```
>
> We also report the best packings we found for other values of n in
>   these forms which are larger than 34, namely, n=37, 40, 42, 43, 46,
>   49, 56, 57, 60, 63, 67, 71, 79, 84, 92, 93, 106, 112, 121, and 254,
>   and also for n=58, 95, 108, 175, 255, 256, 258, and 260. We say that
>   an infinite class of packings of n disks, n=n(1),n(2),...n(k),..., is
>   tight , if [1/d(n(k)+1)−1/d(n(k))] is bounded away from zero as k goes
>   to infinity. We conjecture that some of our infinite classes are
>   tight, others are not tight, and that there are infinitely many tight
>   classes.

http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v2i1a1

and this as well:

> Abstract
>
> This paper presents a computational method to find good, conjecturally
>   optimal coverings of an equilateral triangle with up to 36 equal
>   circles. The algorithm consists of two nested levels: on the inner
>   level the uncovered area of the triangle is minimized by a local
>   optimization routine while the radius of the circles is kept constant.
>   The radius is adapted on the outer level to find a locally optimal
>   covering. Good coverings are obtained by applying the algorithm
>   repeatedly to random initial configurations.
>
> The structures of the coverings are determined and the coordinates of
>   each circle are calculated with high precision using a mathematical
>   model for an idealized physical structure consisting of tensioned bars
>   and frictionless pin joints. Best found coverings of an equilateral
>   triangle with up to 36 circles are displayed, 19 of which are either
>   new or improve on earlier published coverings.

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1045952348

and then finally, this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Larcerax.

I need to draw 53 circles on the boundary of Triangle Like a Rosary. Each circle will be drawn at specific distance.
Out of 53 circles , 5 would be bigger than others(3 on corners(vertices) and other 2 on middle of 2 sides).
Triangle would stand like Cone.